# Notation in limits of integration of double integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was looking at some stuff online about double integrals and I found some [slides](http://www.math.umd.edu/~millson/teaching/STAT400fall18/slides/article17.pdf) from a professor. The following picture is included

[image]

The author says that traditionally, the $x$ - limits are $a$ and $b$, and the $y$ - limits are $c$ and $d$. I just wanted to check if this is really true? Because if it is, I think I have been doing double integrals wrong.

This is how I would do a double integral. Is this correct way?

$$\int_a^b \int_c^d xy \; \; dx dy = \int_a^b \dfrac {x^2y}{2}  \; \bigg \rvert_c^d dy = \int_a^b y \left(\dfrac {d^2}{2} - \dfrac {c^2}{2} \right) dy = \left(\dfrac {d^2}{2} - \dfrac {c^2}{2} \right)\dfrac {y^2}{2}  \bigg \rvert_a^b = \left(\dfrac {d^2}{2} - \dfrac {c^2}{2} \right) \left(\dfrac {b^2}{2} - \dfrac {a^2}{2} \right)$$

Comment: I’ve never seen anyone write them with that convention.

Comment: I've never seen this convention (the professor's) before.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the responses.

Comment: Prof’s convention also seems like just a bad idea.  Inside-out is so natural given Fubini.

Comment: It's funny how the integration limits are reversed when the integral is being evaluated in page 9 of your link. The order is reversed compared to page 8...

Comment: @zxcvber Yeah I noticed that too, was even more confusing lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never have I ever seen your professor's convention in use. As a rule of thumb, symbols that are put on both sides of something, just like the integration symbol $\int$ and the variable, in the form $dx$ (or whatever) are solved inside-out. Treat them as if they were brackets: if you happen to have three brackets, you solve the innermost first, then the middle, and then the outtermost.

At the end of the day double integrals are usually taught in calculus courses with an aim to relate them to iterated integrals, just like the one you have brought, and if you see that as an iterated integral, $c$ and $d$ are the limits with respect to the integration variable $x$, just like you say. You have been doing it right.

On a closing note, I feel curious about what you found. Could you please share a link to them?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The slides are here: http://www.math.umd.edu/~millson/teaching/STAT400fall18/slides/article17.pdf

Comment: The only explanation I can see for this is that
$$
\iint_{[a,b]\times[c,d]} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_a^b dx \int_c^d dy \, f(x,y)
$$

Comment: @Ovi The note right below the notation (the picture you shared in the original post) does acknowledge that the notation is confusing **because of tradition**. This is, in my view, a euphemism for 'I am the only one I know to use this notation'.

Comment: @md2perpe, could you please elaborate a bit more on that? I must confess I don't recall having seen that notation. If I encountered the thing on the right-hand side of the equality, I'd say it equals to $(b-a)(d-c)f(x,y)$, but I bet that's not what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: @SamSkywalker Ah okay thank makes sense; I had read that as "the notation is bad, but it's tradition so we can't change it". But your reading is more accurate I guess

Comment: @SamSkywalker The notation on the right hand side is sometimes used instead of
$$\int_a^b \left( \int_c^d f(x,y) \, dy \right) dx$$
Think of $\int_a^b dx$ as an operator acting on the expression on its right.

Comment: Oh, that does make sense. Thank you!